# Yii: How the title(string) form another table becomes array in view page?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I print some data using foreign key, but I don't how it was converted to array in my view page.

```
echo ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($model->postby_id)->username);
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
    'data' => $model,
    'attributes' => array(`enter code here`
        'id',
        'title',
        'question',
        'detail',
        //'postby_id',
        array(
            'name' => 'Post By',
            'value' => ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($model->postby_id)->username),
        ),
        'verified',
        'verifiedby_id',
        'post_date',
        'hits',
        'status',
    ),
));
```

Comment: What's the result of `ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($model->postby_id)->username)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array(
        'name' => 'Post By',
        'value' => echo ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($model->postby_id)->username),
    ),
```

Or:

```
array(
        'name' => 'Post By',
        'value' => function(){
           echo ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($model->postby_id)->username)
         },
    ),
```

**Update:**
From [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail), "value" *can also be an anonymous function whose return value will be used as a value. The signature of the function should be function($data) where data refers to the data property of the detail view widget.*. I think below solution can help you:

First define a function in your model:

```
 public function getUsername($postby_id)
 {
     return ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($postby_id)->username);
 }
```

Then you can have this in your view:

```
 array(
        'name' => 'Post By',
        'value' =>$model->getUsername($model->postby_id)),
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you @hamed, I tried and got syntax error for both option. IDE tells us that echo is unexpected for first option & } is also unexpected.

Comment: What's the result of `ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($model->postby_id)->username)`?

Comment: It's string as per my desire.

Comment: $a = ucfirst(User::model()->findByPk($model->postby_id)->username);
array(
            'name' => 'Post By',
            'value' => $a[0],
        ),

Now it can print first character of a string.

Comment: Same Error. Error 500, system() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given